# Remainder of a summation (resolved)

Tags: number-theory, summation, contest-math

> Find remainder when
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{16}}\binom{2k}{k}(3\cdot2^{14}+1)(k-1)^{2^{16}-1}$$ is divided by $2^{16}+1$.

I have tried to simplify it term by term,i.e using fermats little theorem and modular simplifications on each term but  the binomial coefficient is very troubling to my calculations.
This problem is from the $\text{OMO}$ $\text{fall}$ $2012$ problem set .

Appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level, please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Alright thanks for the heads up

Comment: Also note that $2^{16} + 1$ is prime and it may help in some way.

Comment: Yes I tried using fermats little theorem on the general term but the binomial coefficient is making it very difficult

Comment: I believe that you quoted the problem incorrectly. The middle term should be $ ( 3 \cdot 2^{14} + 1 ) ^{\color{red}{k}}$. [See the discussion on AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c487h500643p2813314).

Comment: Oh no !alright I think I should close it then thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{16}+1$ is a prime which we may denote as $p$. Neglecting the constant $3\cdot 2^{14}+1$ we have to deal with

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{p-1}\binom{2k}{k}(k-1)^{p-2} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}\frac{1}{k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{k}+2\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}. $$
Then have a look at [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885810000035) or [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509648.pdf).

Comment: That's very helpful! thank you